# How to Iterate this textboxs via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have the following html code

```
<td>
  Question1
   <input type="radio" value="1" name="1" id="1_1">Agree
   <input type="radio" value="2" name="1" id="1_2">Dis-Agree
  <input type="text" size="30" name="1[answer]" id="1_answer" class="answer">
</td>
<td>
  Question2
   <input type="radio" value="1" name="2" id="2_1">Agree
   <input type="radio" value="2" name="2" id="2_2">Dis-Agree
  <input type="text" size="30" name="2[answer]" id="2_answer" class="answer">
</td>
<input type="text" size="30" name="feedback[answers]" id="feedback_answers">
```

What I want to do is

- When user clicks on the radio button it gets the selected value and
  set in text box along with the question (Ex: 1_answer)
- Meanwhile I want to append the same value to the 'feedback_answers'
  text box

I was manage to the first steps, but I cannot get the values from Ex: 1_answer text box to 'feedback_answers' text box, following is my JQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input:radio[type=radio]").click(function() {
       id = $(this).attr('id');
       ids = id.split("_")
       question_id = ids[0]
       answer_id = ids[1]
       $('#' + question_id + '_answer').val(answer_id);
       $(".answer").each(function(index, value){
         alert(this.val)
       });  
});
```

can someone help me, I want to loop through all the 'asnwer' text boxes (Ex: 1_answer) and get all of them to 'feedback_answers' text box.

thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't those answer boxes rather be `<output>` elements than a `<input>`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var feedback_answers = $("#feedback_answers");
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       var ids = id.split("_")
       var question_id = ids[0]
       var answer_id = ids[1];
       var answers = [];
       $('#' + question_id + '_answer').val(answer_id);
       $(".answer").each(function(index, value){
          //alert($(this).val())
          answers.push($(this).val());
       });  
       feedback_answers.val(answers.join());
});
```